# react-native-maps WMSTile in EPSG:4326 format

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, wms

I need to overlay

```
https://xgis.maaamet.ee/xgis2/service/a4au/looduskaitsea?&map_resolution=120.71&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=kr_hoiuala&CRS=EPSG%3A900913&STYLES=&WIDTH={width}&HEIGHT={height}&BBOX={minY}%2C{minX}%2C{maxY}%2C{maxX}
```

url on react-native-maps (working chunk [here](https://xgis.maaamet.ee/xgis2/service/a4au/looduskaitsea?&map_resolution=120.71&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=kr_hoiuala&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=1024&HEIGHT=1024&BBOX=57.3112%2C21.3974%2C60.076%2C28.5544)).

My template needs the {minY},{minX},{maxY},{maxX} in EPSG:4326 format not EPSG:900913

and I've read [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/ebb13b55e63a25dd5f306f309d1752b939296115/lib/components/MapWMSTile.js) that {minY},{minX},{maxY},{maxX} will be given in EPSG:900913

Is there a way to transform EPSG:900913 coordinates in WMS Tile url Template to EPSG:4326?

Answer (score 0):

It only replace {width}, {height}, {minY}, {minX}, {maxY}, {maxX} so if you wanna use EPSG:4326 format, just pass srs=EPSG:4326 in the url template